# Data not being parsed by middleware

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, middleware

Why isn't my form data being added to the object sent to MongoDB cloud. It sends an empty object. But if I hard code the values they are added:

This posts an empty object {}:

```
  const formData = new FormData({
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    email: email
  });
```

Result:

```
{}
{ _id: new ObjectId("646afa5f7d803b6059b0208f"), __v: 0 }
```

But this will post hardcoded fields successfully:

```
const formData = new FormData({
firstName: "firstName",
lastName: "lastName",
email: "email"});
```

Result:

```
    {}
    {
  firstName: 'firstName',
  lastName: 'lastName',
  email: 'email',
  _id: new ObjectId("646afaaed9b1db5dc17dd306"),
  __v: 0
  }
```

Here is my models/formModel.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

// Create a schema for the data you want to save in MongoDB
const formDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    // required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    // required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    // required: true
  }
});

module.exports = formDataSchema;
```

Here is my app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const connect = require('./config/db')
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const formDataSchema = require("./models/formModel");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
connect();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.get("/favicon.ico", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("/index.html");
});


app.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
  const { firstName, lastName, email } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body)
  const FormData = mongoose.model("FormData", formDataSchema);
  
  const formData = new FormData({
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    email: email
  });
  
  
  try {
    const savedData = await formData.save();
    console.log(savedData);
    res.redirect('/success.html');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.redirect('/fail.html');
  }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on ${PORT}`));
```

Here is index.html:

```html
<form action="/signup" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="first-name" class="form-control"
            placeholder="First Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="last-name" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Last Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> SUBMIT </button>
</form>
```

I suspect the issue is in how the form data is sent to the post method. I can only tell that it looks like nothing is being sent based on the empty brackets when I console log req.body.

Comment: _"I suspect the issue is in how the form data is sent to the post method"_... so what does your client-side code look like?

Comment: I added the body of index.html above.

Comment: The issue is your app expects JSON request bodies but you're sending `multipart/form-data`. Remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from your `<form>` and add in `app.use(express.urlencoded())` to your Express middleware. Should all work as expected then.

Comment: Yes! how did you figure that out? I'll mark this as the correct answer once I find out how.

Comment: _"how did you figure that out?"_ been doing this a long time and have made a lot of mistakes 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues...

1. Your Express app is only configured to handle `application/json` request bodies because you have only added the following body-parsing middleware

   > ```js
   > app.use(express.json())
   > ```
2. Your form is sending the request body as `multipart/form-data` which requires special middleware like [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

   Typically, you only need to use `multipart/form-data` when uploading files.

To solve these, remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from your `<form>` or replace it with `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` (this is the [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype)) and add in [the following body-parsing middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded)

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

Comment: I can't believe how fast you solved it! thanks very much for your expertise, Phil!